# Fundamental weights of $A_n$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I have the following problem: Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra of type $A_n$. We choose $e_i^*-e_{i+1}^*$ as simple roots. Is there a closed formula for the fundamental weights? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If I understand the notation well, the $i$th fundamental weight should be $e_1^*+\dots+e_i^*$.

Comment: To me it looks like the $n$ simple roots are written as vectors of the zero-sum subspace of $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$. While your vector has the correct inner products, it is not in the space spanned by the roots. The remedy is to project! The vector $\vec{r_i}=e_1^*+e_2^*+\cdots+e_i^*$ has inner product $i$ with the normal of the zero-sum subspace $\vec{n}=e_1^*+e_2^*+\cdots+e_{n+1}^*$. This means that the $i$th fundamental weight would be
$$\lambda_i=\vec{r_i}-\frac{\langle \vec{r_i},\vec{n}\rangle}{||\vec{n}||^2}\vec{n}=
\frac1{n+1}[(n+1-i)(e_1^*+e_2^*+\cdots+e_i^*)-i(e_{i+1}^*+\cdots+e_{n+1}^*)].$$

Comment: Weights (and thus also the simple roots) are linear functionals on the space of tracefree diagonal matrices. (Mostly one works over $\mathbb C$ and the inner product does not really play a role.) The $e_i^*$ are well defined as such functionals. They are redundant since $e_1^*+\dots+e_{n+1}^*=0$, but this does not really matter. In that sense, one can use as well your version since the difference to mine is a multiple of $e_1^*+\dots+e_{n+1}^*$ represents the zero functional. Weights represent eigenvalues in representations, and the $e_i^*$ occur in the standard representation.

Comment: Ok. That is certainly a way of looking at it that makes sense. It's been a while, and I apparently default to the geometric Euclidean picture, where this kind of calculations take place in the $\Bbb{R}$-span of the simple roots.